# Need to retrieve data from cookie that holds the logged on client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have two different pages in my WP7 Application, Page1 and Page2. On the first page the user is asked to log in using the .NET membership API through a WCF-service. When the user is logged in this client is saved in a cookie.

When the user fills in their username and password an clicks OK, the application redirects this person to the next page using the NavigationService. But after the person is redirected to Page2 I can not access the cookie of the current logged in user.

I can retrieve the logged in user on Page1 where the CookieContainer is created and the client is saved to this specific container. On Page2 I want to use the same cookie as in Page1, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save user credentials in isolatedStorage and use those credentials in other pages [IsolatedStorage Documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#Y0)

Comment: it is a great solution, pay extra attention when logging the user out. this storage is only cleared when you clear it manually yourself or uninstall the application.
Most Welcome Btw :)